# Knockout bind error, unable to bind viewModel inside iFrame

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding, binding

I'm trying to bind a knockout template and just cannot break the problem down, there are a million thing that I've tried.

and I'm pretty lost at the moment for any ideas, I've been debugging it since days.

The same template is also fetched on some other page and it works fine.

I've tried printing the $data object and it shows that the data is available, however on that same template it does not bind
the values.

I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "with: function (){return selectedView }"`
`Message: Unable to process binding "template: function (){return {name:templateName,data:data} }"`
basically a chain of error from there as the template is not binded.
here's some of the view code :

```
#page-hold{data: {role: 'page', theme: 'a'}}
  .container{ "data-bind" => "with: selectedView"}
    %div{ "data-bind" => "template : {name: templateName, data: data}" , data: {role: 'content'}}


%script{ "id" => "tpl_landing", "type" => "text/html"}

//html partials
```

Data object looks like this

```
{
  "views": [
    {
      "title": "landing",
      "templateName": "tpl_landing",
      "data": {
        "base": {
        /// data
        }
```

**Latest Update**: I've gained deeper insight of the problem and after debugging a bit more I've found out that the viewModel($data object) can be accessed inside the iframe but it does not bind or output anything on the page apart from the $data object, which gives me a JSON of all the data. Would like to know why the data is not getting binded when I can see it exists.

Anyone who can help me debug this?

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you can try your application in Google Chrome, which might provide more details on the error.

Comment: I'm already using Chrome and that's all it throws back. Is there a better way to leverage the $data object on a page? Thanks.

Comment: If you run your page with the Developer tools open, you should also get a stack trace for the error. Can you try that? Also is there any more detail about what the TypeError is caused by?

Comment: The only concrete reason I've found after digging endlessly is trying to bind $data to the iframe, although I've had no success in implementing that, I'm trying something like: http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/NnT78/10/ but when I post it before the ko.applyBindings in my js file, it returns an error and fails to run.

Comment: That jsFiddle has the iframe content generated from JS code. Is that what you're doing or are you loading a separate HTML page? See http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/GYRUX/

Comment: I'm trying to load the main template in the iframe but it doesn't have access to the data. The example you've shared uses an src attribute which isn't the case with me. I'm using an iframe which loads, mobile/desktop etc templates based on what the user selects, would ideally want the $data always available to the iframe

Answer (score 1):

Knockout supports cross-window binding (sharing a view model between windows), but it doesn't directly support sharing templates between windows. (You could probably write a custom `templateEngine`, but that's pretty advanced.)

I came up with a binding that applies a template and binds the `<iframe>` that I think will do what you want.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.iframeTemplate = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var iframedoc = element.contentDocument,
            options = valueAccessor(),
            templateSource = ko.templateEngine.prototype.makeTemplateSource(ko.unwrap(options.template)),
            templateText = templateSource.text(),
            templateNodes = ko.utils.parseHtmlFragment(templateText, iframedoc),
            iframebody = iframedoc.body;

        ko.virtualElements.setDomNodeChildren(iframebody, templateNodes);
        ko.applyBindings(options.data, iframebody);
    }
};
```

Usage example: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/udhm4qj4/

Comment: Firstly, thank you for taking the time to assess it in-depth!  Fixed some typos with the above example and here's a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h4re864j/1/ . I'll try the templateEngine approach and work something out, thanks for pointing me in the right direction, cheers! : ]

Comment: Oops. I'm not sure how those "typos" got in. They're fixed now.